# animating an observablecollection move operation in the UI wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wrappanel bound to an observablecolelction.

Is there a way to animate the movement of items in the UI when the collection is changed in the code behind? Kind of like the fluid movement of windows tiles style metro apps?

Any design ideas of how to go about this will be appreciated.

Right now, all I can think of is animating the layout chaging event?

Thanks

Comment: IF you downvote, can you please explain why?

Comment: most likely because you are asking for code samples rather than posting your attempt and asking for assistance with fixing problems or unexpected results.  As a Tai chi sifu told me.  if you do something then I can fix your mistakes, but if you don't do anything then there is nothing to fix.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense...but I dont even know where to begin...I dont have experience with animations.

Comment: start with a google on animating an observablecollection move operation in the UI wpf.   May not give you the answer you need but can point you to something to refine your search.  Most likely someone somewhere has done what you are trying

Answer (score 2):

I've needed such thing in the past and -as I remember- I ended using a slightly modified version of the sample provided here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/devdave/layout-transitions-an-animatable-wrappanel

This sample is somewhat advanced and supports animating the items when any modification is made to the collection (adding items, deleting items, resizing the panel)

On the other hand if what you need is a simple animation at the item level only (e.g. when an item is appearing/disappearing) it's much simpler you can build an `ItemTemplate`  with a control that has an `EventTrigger` for the relevant event. This example will animate the item when added:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" Height="300">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="Red" Margin="4" Opacity="0">
                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform Y="20" />
                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <Rectangle.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.6" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).Y" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.4" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Rectangle.Triggers>
                </Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Width="60" Height="40" Content="Add Item" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
    ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        itemsControl.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        items.Add("New Item");
    }
```

Comment: Can you do the same as the item is being removed?  I have tried hooking to the event "Unloaded", but it seems this is fired AFTER the item is removed, so the animation never takes place.  I am looking for a way to control fire an animation RIGHT BEFORE the item is removed from the list, so I can animate its disapearing (with opacity or height, just like in your example).  Is there any way to do this?